# Facebook convas page must end with backslash (directory) how to make servlet end with backslash

Tags: java, servlets

when i direct convas page to my servlet it fails as http 404 the resource is not available,
i changed the uri-pattern in web.xml of servlet adding backslash when i try to run locally it gives me same error http 404.
how to direct facebook application to my servlet adding backslash to it ?
iam deploying my servlet over TomCat 6.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a servlet mapping similar to this:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>unlikephoto</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/unlikephoto/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

You should then be able to access the url with a backslash at the end.